# How to create a constructor function in javascript so that if two instance created with 'new' keyword the value of instance1 === instance2 return true

Tags: javascript

I was finding a way, if I can make this code work. I cannot use prototype and I want to create the instance using "new" keyword only.

```
function Employee(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var e1 = new Employee();
var e2 = new Employee();
e1 === e2; // Expected result should be true.
```

Comment: Do you want all calls to `new Employee()` to return the same object regardless of what name is passed in? Or should they only return the same object if the name is the same?

Comment: You could use `e1 instanceof Employee && e2 instanceof Employee`.

Comment: Yes regardless the name we pass. Eg: :
var e1 = new Employee('a');
var e2 = new Employee('b');
e1 === e2;//True;

Comment: the name of `e2` overwrites the name of `e1`.

Comment: Basically, if we create 100 instances also; all should return true if we compare with each other using '==='and the instance should be created with 'new' keyword only.

Comment: You can't have e1 === e2 (true), unless e1 is the same instance of Employee as e2.  There is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: `Basically, if we create 100 instances also; all should return true` you won't be creating 100 instances though. You'll be creating one instance. If `e1 === e2`, that means they are literally the same instance. If you want 100 instances and just wnat to check that they are the same type, then `===` is not the right way to go.

Comment: Is there anyway if I can manipulate 'this' of the constructor function(Employee)?

Comment: you could use a singleton, but you have only the first name of the first instance as data. maybe you write what you really want with this construct.

Comment: Actually, this was a question asked to me with the same example. So I am trying to figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use the `new` keyword and you want the result to be a singleton, then you can do something like this:

```js
var Employee = (function () {
   var instance;
   return function Employee(name) {
      if (!instance) {
         this.name = name;
         instance = this;
      }
      return instance;
   }
})();

var a = new Employee('a');
var b = new Employee('b');

// They pass the === check
console.log('===', a === b);

// But they have the same name because they're the same object
console.log('a.name', a.name);
console.log('b.name', b.name);

// And changing one changes them both because, again, they're the same object
a.name = 'z';
console.log('a.name', a.name);
console.log('b.name', b.name);
```

Normally when you call a constructor, `new` creates a new object, which you can add to by accessing `this`, and then that newly created object is returned. However, if you explicitly return something from your constructor, then that object will be used instead of the one that `new` would normally create. So i've set up the code so that the constructor always returns the same instance, which i've then trapped inside an IIFE to make it "private".

But notice that since a and b are literally the same object, they both have the same name. In my case, the first name sticks and the second one is ignored. You could modify the code to make the second name overwrite the first one, but it's impossible for them to have different names while still meeting your requirements that a === b.

Comment: Thanks .. I think this is the solution I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

`new` sets the `contructor` property of the object. If you want to check if they were created by the same constructor, you could compare those:

```js
function Employee(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var e1 = new Employee('foo');
var e2 = new Employee('bar');
var x = new Date();

console.log(e1.constructor === e2.constructor); // true
console.log(e1.constructor === x.constructor);  // false
```